# how to build all-in-one installer from source openerp?

Tags: odoo

I downloaded the source from nightly update official website, and I found that 
there was a **setup.py** and **setup.nsi**(using NSIS) in the folder.

So does it mean that I can build my own all-in-one installer from the source? I wanna add new addon such as aeroo report to all-in-one installer.

But how to do it ? I can't find any doc descripting this.

Any help would be very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.First make sure that your new module "aeroo" is working fine and then take a backup of your database.Now go to machine where you want to install and restore this database with the same database name.Then you need to copy the files of your custom module to installed openerp path(../Openerp/Addons/). Restart your Openerp server and you will get your required changes to your new machine.